# get runtime from oraclebulkcopy for progressbar

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-code

Good night friends,

i am uploading a file
from heavy excel (200 MB) to oracle and I'm working on it in the background with BackgroundWorker1, but I have trouble calculating the execution time or the time it will take to execute oraclebulkcopy to be able to loop and update the counter and pass it to a progressbar .

I am trying with:

```
for i: 0 to row_file_excel
BackgroundWorker1.reportprogress (i)
next
```

but it does not return the desired result, I must replace row_file_excel with the time it will take to load the oraclebulkcopy but I don't know how to find the work time.

If it is not possible to obtain the time, what else could I do?

I will appreciate any help

Thank you so much,

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim _connString As String = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.10.100.1)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = ORACLE))); User Id=USER; password=PASS;"
        Dim rutacarpeta As String
        Dim NombreArchivo As String
        Dim tablaBBDD As String
        'Dim ot As OracleTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
        Using conn As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection(_connString)
            conn.Open()
            Dim ot As OracleTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
            Try

                rutacarpeta = "C:\2021\"
                NombreArchivo = "FILE_0.xlsx"
                tablaBBDD = "FILE_TEST"
                Dim xlsxConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;';"
                xlsxConn = String.Format(xlsxConn, rutacarpeta + NombreArchivo).Trim()

                Using excel_con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(xlsxConn)
                    excel_con.Open()
                    'Dim hoja As String = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing).Rows(0)()
                    Dim command As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter ("SELECT * FROM [FILE$]", excel_con)

                    Dim dtset As new dataset
                    command.fill(dtset)
                     dim dr as datatable =dtset.tables(0)
                     row_file_excel=dr.rows.count

                    Using bulkCopy As OracleBulkCopy = New OracleBulkCopy(conn)
                        bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 90000
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tablaBBDD

                  for i: 0 to row_file_excel '***here I want to calculate the execution time of the load (bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr))******
                      BackgroundWorker1.reportprogress(i)
                  next                            

                   bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr)

                        ot.Commit()

                        bulkCopy.Close()
                    End Using
                End Using

            Catch ex As Exception
                Try
                    ot.Rollback()
                Catch ex1 As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex1.Message)
                End Try

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

            End Try
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used `OracleBulkCopy` so I'm not going to try to write a detailed code example. I just read the relevant documentation, so I can indicate what I think you should do based on that.

When you retrieve the data, you can get the total number of records to import and assign that to the `Maximum` property of your `ProgressBar`. You can set the `NotifyAfter` property and handle the `RowsCopied` event of your `OracleBulkCopy` object to be notified each time that many rows has been copied. The smaller the number you specify, the more often the event will be raised and the finer-grained your progress will be, but the more you will slow down the overall process. You would increase the `Value` of your `ProgressBar` by the number of rows copied on each event.

I'm not sure what the `e` parameter of the event handler will provide you. If it provides the number of rows copied so far then you can just assign that to the `Value` property. If it doesn't provide a count then you can just add the value of `NotifyAfter` to the `Value` property.